# input of user not looping the right way, loops more than once or loops incorrectly

Tags: java, loops, input

here is where the user inputs for picking a weapon as he wishes.

```
        String ans = "Y";
    while (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {
        while (monster >= 0 && you >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nPick Weapon!");
            String input = keyboard.next();
```

Here is the piece of code i am having a problem with

```
        else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("energy"))
            {

                System.out.println("\nYou have 0.0 energy and cannot use you have to wait for 5 seconds for it to charge up half or take a hit and go ALL OUT BABY");
                try
                {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
                    System.out.println("\nSystem has charges and is ready for use, press 1");
                    int inputattack = keyboard.nextInt();
                    energy += 3000;
                    if (inputattack == 1)
                    {
                        String inputofretry = "Y";
                        if ((energy >= 3000) && (inputofretry.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")))
                        {
                            System.out.println("\nYou have used all of your energy and did a damage of 1000 to the moster!");
                            monster -= 1000;
                            energy -= 3000;
                            System.out.println("\nNow the monster has a health of " + monster);
                            ----------------->System.out.println("\nWould you like to use up your other half also or  use a diffrent weapon");
                            inputofretry = keyboard.next();
                            if (inputofretry.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                            {
                                ans = "Y";
                            }//end of break out of if
                        }//end of energy half use

                        else if (energy <= 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("\nRan out of energy and you have been redirected to the refill of energy");
                            ans = "Y";
                        }

                }//end of input attack
```

The problem is happening when the User Presses "Y" to use energy again, it doesn't go through the if again.

Main problem is that when i answer the  question  wrong like a input of answer to wither pick a weapon or pick a the same one (also when i say yes to the pick the same one option at the line where i have marked ---> it still breaks out of the loop instead of staying in it it)  it asks me to pick a weapon 3 times instead of 1 and i don't know why and also SORRY for the long code but i would like to ask users if they could make my code any better if they can thanks i am a SUPER noob to java and i am new to stack so i am a noob to everything.

So please ask me any questions about the code if you can

thank you in advance for anyone who helped!!

WHOLE CODE

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class nestedif
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("\nWelcome\n");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int bombs = 60;
        int arrows = 2;
        boolean bow = true;
        double energy = 0.0;
        double monster = 3000;
        int you = 1000;

        System.out.println("\nMonster has appeared!!\n");

        System.out.println("\nHeres your inventory");
        System.out.println("\n60 bombs");
        System.out.println("\n2 ultra arrows");
        System.out.println("\n0.0 energy, you can recharge later if  you choose to do so");





        String ans = "Y";
        while (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            while (monster >= 0 && you >= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nPick Weapon!");
                String input = keyboard.next();

                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("bombs"))
                {
                    if (bombs >= 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nYou have chosen Bombs\n");
                        System.out.println("\nHit 9 to attack with big bombs which is -2 bombs or hit 8 for small bomb which is -1\n");
                        int choice1 = keyboard.nextInt();

                        if (choice1 == 9)
                        {
                                System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to attack with a big bomb 2 bombs ahve been taken from your inventory");
                                System.out.println("\nYou damaged the monster by 800\n");
                                monster -= 800;
                                bombs -= 2;
                                System.out.println("Now the monster has the health of" + monster + "\n");

                                System.out.println("\nHit Y to choose another weapon or N to back out of the fight");
                                ans = keyboard.next();
                         }//if end

                        else if (choice1 == 8)
                        {
                                System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to attack with a small bomb");
                                System.out.println("\nYou damaged the monster by 400\n");
                                monster -= 400;
                                bombs -= 1;
                                System.out.println("Now the monster has the health of" + monster + "\n");

                                System.out.println("\nHit Y to choose another weapon or N to back out of the fight");
                                ans = keyboard.next();

                        }//else if end of small bombs

                    }//end of if loop to do something i dont know i just leant this
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nYour bombs have depleted, please choose another weapon of your choice!");
                    }

                }//Bombs end

                else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("arrows"))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nYou have chosen arrows as your weapon!");
                    if ((bow == true) && (arrows >= 1))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nPlease press 1 to attack");
                        double arrowinput = keyboard.nextInt();

                        if (arrowinput == 1)
                        {
                        System.out.println("\nYou have only " + arrows + " left");
                        System.out.println("\nYou used Arrow and damaged the monster by 500 ");
                        monster -= 500;
                        arrows --;
                        System.out.println("\nNow the monster has the health of " + monster);
                        System.out.println("\nThe monster is still alive and is attacking you you have to kill it NOW CHOOSE A WEAPON SIR");
                        ans = keyboard.next();
                        }//end of attack and IF
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("\nYou have to chosen to be attacked by the monster and be eaten");
                            ans.equals("Y");
                        }//end of else
                    }//end of if to use the arrows and boolean

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nYou chose not to use the arrows now arrow is or you have run out of arrows arrow is unusable");
                        bow = false;
                    }//end of else to check for arrows

                }//end of bow

                else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("energy"))
                {

                    System.out.println("\nYou have 0.0 energy and cannot use you have to wait for 5 seconds for it to charge up half or take a hit and go ALL OUT BABY");
                    try
                    {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                        System.out.println("\nSystem has charges and is ready for use, press 1");
                        int inputattack = keyboard.nextInt();
                        energy += 3000;
                        if (inputattack == 1)
                        {
                            String inputofretry = "Y";
                            if ((energy >= 3000) && (inputofretry.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")))
                            {
                                System.out.println("\nYou have used all of your energy and did a damage of 1000 to the moster!");
                                monster -= 1000;
                                energy -= 3000;
                                System.out.println("\nNow the monster has a health of " + monster);
                                System.out.println("\nWould you like to use up your other half also or  use a diffrent weapon");
                                inputofretry = keyboard.next();
                                if (inputofretry.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }//end of break out of if
                            }//end of energy half use

                            else if (energy <= 0)
                            {
                                System.out.println("\nRan out of energy and you have been redirected to the refill of energy");
                                ans = "Y";
                            }

                    }//end of input attack



                }//end of energy

            }//end of check for health
            break;

        }//While to change weapon


        if (you > monster)
        {
        System.out.println("\t\t\nYou have defeated the monster and have conquered the land of void so be happy!!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\nYou have died and have bought a great dishono..... wait a minute you have 2 lives get yo ass up there and fight like aa man");
        }
    }//end of main
}//end of class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
I marked the places where I have made some changes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class nestedif{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("\nWelcome\n");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int bombs = 60;
    int arrows = 2;
    boolean bow = true;
    double energy = 0.0;
    double monster = 3000;
    int you = 1000;

    System.out.println("\nMonster has appeared!!\n");

    System.out.println("\nHeres your inventory");
    System.out.println("\n60 bombs");
    System.out.println("\n2 ultra arrows");
    System.out.println("\n0.0 energy, you can recharge later if  you choose to do so");





    String ans = "Y";
    //change 1
    System.out.println("\nPick Weapon!");
    String input = keyboard.next();
    while(!(input.equalsIgnoreCase("bombs")) && !(input.equalsIgnoreCase("arrows")) && !(input.equalsIgnoreCase("energy"))){
        System.out.println("\nInvalid Weapon...\nRe-pick Weapon!");
        input = keyboard.next();
        if((input.equalsIgnoreCase("bombs")) && (input.equalsIgnoreCase("arrows")) && (input.equalsIgnoreCase("energy"))){
            break;
        }
    }
    //end of change 1

    while (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {
        while (monster >= 0 && you >= 0)
        {
            //change 2.1
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                System.out.println("\nPick Weapon!");
                input = keyboard.next();
            }
            //end of change 2.1

            else{//change 2.2 (the else of the if statement above)
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("bombs"))
                {
                    if (bombs >= 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nYou have chosen Bombs\n");
                        System.out.println("\nHit 9 to attack with big bombs which is -2 bombs or hit 8 for small bomb which is -1\n");
                        int choice1 = keyboard.nextInt();

                        if (choice1 == 9)
                        {
                                System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to attack with a big bomb 2 bombs ahve been taken from your inventory");
                                System.out.println("\nYou damaged the monster by 800\n");
                                monster -= 800;
                                bombs -= 2;
                                System.out.println("Now the monster has the health of" + monster + "\n");

                                System.out.println("\nHit Y to choose another weapon or N to back out of the fight");
                                ans = keyboard.next();
                         }//if end

                        else if (choice1 == 8)
                        {
                                System.out.println("\nYou have chosen to attack with a small bomb");
                                System.out.println("\nYou damaged the monster by 400\n");
                                monster -= 400;
                                bombs -= 1;
                                System.out.println("Now the monster has the health of" + monster + "\n");

                                System.out.println("\nHit Y to choose another weapon or N to back out of the fight");
                                ans = keyboard.next();

                        }//else if end of small bombs

                    }//end of if loop to do something i dont know i just leant this
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nYour bombs have depleted, please choose another weapon of your choice!");
                    }

                }//Bombs end

                else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("arrows"))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nYou have chosen arrows as your weapon!");
                    if ((bow == true) && (arrows >= 1))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nPlease press 1 to attack");
                        double arrowinput = keyboard.nextInt();

                        if (arrowinput == 1)
                        {
                        System.out.println("\nYou have only " + arrows + " left");
                        System.out.println("\nYou used Arrow and damaged the monster by 500 ");
                        monster -= 500;
                        arrows --;
                        System.out.println("\nNow the monster has the health of " + monster);
                        System.out.println("\nThe monster is still alive and is attacking you you have to kill it NOW CHOOSE A WEAPON SIR");
                        ans = keyboard.next();
                        }//end of attack and IF
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("\nYou have to chosen to be attacked by the monster and be eaten");
                            ans.equals("Y");
                        }//end of else
                    }//end of if to use the arrows and boolean

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nYou chose not to use the arrows now arrow is or you have run out of arrows arrow is unusable");
                        bow = false;
                    }//end of else to check for arrows

                }//end of bow

                else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("energy"))
                {

                    System.out.println("\nYou have 0.0 energy and cannot use you have to wait for 5 seconds for it to charge up half or take a hit and go ALL OUT BABY");
                    try
                    {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                        System.out.println("\nSystem has charges and is ready for use, press 1");
                        int inputattack = keyboard.nextInt();
                        energy += 3000;
                        if (inputattack == 1)
                        {
                            String inputofretry = "Y";
                            if ((energy >= 3000) && (inputofretry.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")))
                            {
                                System.out.println("\nYou have used all of your energy and did a damage of 1000 to the moster!");
                                monster -= 1000;
                                energy -= 3000;
                                System.out.println("\nNow the monster has a health of " + monster);
                                System.out.println("\nWould you like to use up your other half also or  use a diffrent weapon");
                                inputofretry = keyboard.next();
                                if (inputofretry.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }//end of break out of if
                            }//end of energy half use

                            else if (energy <= 0)
                            {
                                System.out.println("\nRan out of energy and you have been redirected to the refill of energy");
                                ans = "Y";
                            }

                    }//end of input attack



                }//end of energy

            }

        }//end of check for health
        break;

    }//While to change weapon


    if (you > monster)
    {
    System.out.println("\t\t\nYou have defeated the monster and have conquered the land of void so be happy!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\nYou have died and have bought a great dishono..... wait a minute you have 2 lives get yo ass up there and fight like aa man");
    }
}//end of main
```

}//end of class

Comment: this breaks out of the whole loop but i have multiple loops and i want it to break out of only one and the "N " is working fine its the "Y" part which is messing up

Comment: The code you've posted is not sufficient enough for me to fully analyse it. It'd be better if you posted the whole of it, or at least the part of the code you're having problem with, ALONG with the loop it's related to.

Comment: Check my edited answer, and see if it matches what you wanted to do.

Comment: Hey this works but when i press "n" for the energy part it breaks out of the whole loop but others work perfectly Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should remove the "break;" at the "else" part of "energy", and print something like "choose another weapon" and reset "ans" to "y".

Comment: yes when i reset the ans to yes it loops back to the energy part and not the pick another weapon but whatever this is good enough!! thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

I dont have java on my pc right now. I suspect it might be due to `\n` remaining in the buffer because of `nextInt()`.Try this `inputofretry.nextLine();` after `System.out.println("\nWould you like to use up your other half also or  use a diffrent weapon");` and before taking the input.

Comment: Nope dint work . Says error when I have nextline hey but thanks

Comment: `nextLine();` //Capital L. jst sayin incase u erred on that.// I mean [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) one

Comment: Yea used nextLine but when I used deliminator it worked but same error